# Как показать / скрывать burger-menu и элементы навигации при определенних ширинах экрана

Tags: javascript, css

Есть такой не большой *burger-menu*.

Как сделать чтобы только при маленких ширинах экрана  показывалсья *burger-menu*  и значок = соответсвенно.

И при больших екранах  элементы просто выравнивались по центру то есть показались а burger-menu скрывалсья.

```js
(function(){
    var burger = document.querySelector('.burger-container'),
        header = document.querySelector('.header');
    
    burger.onclick = function() {
        header.classList.toggle('menu-opened');
    }
}());
// let w = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

// if(w < 768) {
//   let menuItem =document.querySelectorAll(".menu-item");
//   for(var i = 0; i < menuItem.length;i++){
//     menuItem[i].style.display = "none";
//   }
// }
// if(w > 768){
//   let burgerContainer = document.querySelector(".burger-container");
//   burgerContainer.style.display = "none";
// }
```

```css
/* nav menu */
body {
  height:1000px;
}
#window {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    width:100%;
}
.header {
    margin:0 auto;
    padding: 0 22px;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out, background 1s ease-out;
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
    z-index: 1;
}
.menu {
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    height: 44px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 2.3em;
}
.menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#fff;
}
.gn-logo {
    height: 40px;
    width: 60px;
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
}
.menu li a {
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom right, #eee, #333);
     -webkit-background-clip: text;
     -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
/* ----______------ */
#window .header .burger-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
          transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
#window .header .burger-container #burger {
  width: 18px;
  height: 8px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: -4px auto 0;
  top: 50%;
}
#window .header .burger-container #burger .bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background: #FFF;
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
#window .header .burger-container #burger .bar.topBar {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
          transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
}
#window .header .burger-container #burger .bar.btmBar {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(6px) rotate(0deg);
          transform: translateY(6px) rotate(0deg);
}
#window .header ul.menu {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0px 48px 0;
  list-style: none;
} 
#window .header ul.menu li.menu-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  margin-top: 5px;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.15) translateY(-30px);
          transform: scale(1.15) translateY(-30px);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99), -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99), opacity 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99), opacity 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99), -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
}
#window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 0.49s;
}
#window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 0.42s;
}
#window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: 0.35s;
}
#window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(4) {
  transition-delay: 0.28s;
}
#window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(5) {
  transition-delay: 0.21s;
}
#window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(6) {
  transition-delay: 0.14s;
}
#window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(7) {
  transition-delay: 0.07s;
}
#window .header ul.menu li.menu-item a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: "Ek Mukta", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 2.35;
  font-weight: 200;
  width: 100%;
}
#window .header.menu-opened {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in, background 0.5s ease-in;
  transition-delay: 0.25s;
}
#window .header.menu-opened .burger-container {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
          transform: rotate(90deg);
} 
#window .header.menu-opened .burger-container #burger .bar {
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
#window .header.menu-opened .burger-container #burger .bar.topBar {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(4px) rotate(45deg);
          transform: translateY(4px) rotate(45deg);
}
#window .header.menu-opened .burger-container #burger .bar.btmBar {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(3px) rotate(-45deg);
          transform: translateY(3px) rotate(-45deg);
}
#window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1) translateY(0px);
          transform: scale(1) translateY(0px);
  opacity: 1;
} 
#window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 0.27s;
}
#window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 0.34s;
}
#window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: 0.41s;
}
#window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(4) {
  transition-delay: 0.48s;
}
#window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(5) {
  transition-delay: 0.55s;
}
#window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(6) {
  transition-delay: 0.62s;
}
#window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(7) {
  transition-delay: 0.69s;
}
```

```html
<nav id="window" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row header">
          <div class="burger-container">
            <div id="burger">
              <div class="bar topBar"></div>
              <div class="bar btmBar"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li class="menu-item">
                    <a class="navbar-brand gn-logo" href="#">
                        <img class="navbar-brand gn-logo" alt="logo" src="assets/Abeja_formatted.png"/>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a class="" href="#">Samsung</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a class="" href="#">iPhone</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a class="" href="#">Xiaomi</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a class="" href="#">One Plus</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a class="" href="#">LG</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a class="" href="#">Acer</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто надо было в определенное место кода добавить нужный media запрос

```js
(function(){
    var burger = document.querySelector('.burger-container'),
        header = document.querySelector('.header');
    
    burger.onclick = function() {
        header.classList.toggle('menu-opened');
    }
}());
// let w = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

// if(w < 768) {
//   let menuItem =document.querySelectorAll(".menu-item");
//   for(var i = 0; i < menuItem.length;i++){
//     menuItem[i].style.display = "none";
//   }
// }
// if(w > 768){
//   let burgerContainer = document.querySelector(".burger-container");
//   burgerContainer.style.display = "none";
// }
```

```css
/* nav menu */
body {
  height:1000px;
}
#window {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    width:100%;
}
.header {
    margin:0 auto;
    padding: 0 22px;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out, background 1s ease-out;
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
    z-index: 1;
}
.menu {
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    height: 44px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 2.3em;
}
.menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#fff;
}
.gn-logo {
    height: 40px;
    width: 60px;
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
}
.menu li a {
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom right, #eee, #333);
     -webkit-background-clip: text;
     -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
/* ----______------ */
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #window .header .burger-container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
    -webkit-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  }
  #window .header .burger-container #burger {
    width: 18px;
    height: 8px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: -4px auto 0;
    top: 50%;
  }
  #window .header .burger-container #burger .bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background: #FFF;
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
    transition-delay: 0s;
  }
  #window .header .burger-container #burger .bar.topBar {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
            transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  #window .header .burger-container #burger .bar.btmBar {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(6px) rotate(0deg);
            transform: translateY(6px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  #window .header ul.menu {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 0px 48px 0;
    list-style: none;
  } 
  #window .header ul.menu li.menu-item {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
    margin-top: 5px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.15) translateY(-30px);
            transform: scale(1.15) translateY(-30px);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99), -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
    transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99), opacity 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
    transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99), opacity 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99), -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  }
  #window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(1) {
    transition-delay: 0.49s;
  }
  #window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(2) {
    transition-delay: 0.42s;
  }
  #window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(3) {
    transition-delay: 0.35s;
  }
  #window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(4) {
    transition-delay: 0.28s;
  }
  #window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(5) {
    transition-delay: 0.21s;
  }
  #window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(6) {
    transition-delay: 0.14s;
  }
  #window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(7) {
    transition-delay: 0.07s;
  }
  #window .header ul.menu li.menu-item a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: "Ek Mukta", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 2.35;
    font-weight: 200;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #window .header.menu-opened {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in, background 0.5s ease-in;
    transition-delay: 0.25s;
  }
  #window .header.menu-opened .burger-container {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
            transform: rotate(90deg);
  } 
  #window .header.menu-opened .burger-container #burger .bar {
    transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
  }
  #window .header.menu-opened .burger-container #burger .bar.topBar {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(4px) rotate(45deg);
            transform: translateY(4px) rotate(45deg);
  }
  #window .header.menu-opened .burger-container #burger .bar.btmBar {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(3px) rotate(-45deg);
            transform: translateY(3px) rotate(-45deg);
  }
  #window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) translateY(0px);
            transform: scale(1) translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  } 
  #window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(1) {
    transition-delay: 0.27s;
  }
  #window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(2) {
    transition-delay: 0.34s;
  }
  #window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(3) {
    transition-delay: 0.41s;
  }
  #window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(4) {
    transition-delay: 0.48s;
  }
  #window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(5) {
    transition-delay: 0.55s;
  }
  #window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(6) {
    transition-delay: 0.62s;
  }
  #window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(7) {
    transition-delay: 0.69s;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav id="window" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row header">
          <div class="burger-container">
            <div id="burger">
              <div class="bar topBar"></div>
              <div class="bar btmBar"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li class="menu-item">
                    <a class="navbar-brand gn-logo" href="#">
                        <img class="navbar-brand gn-logo" alt="logo" src="assets/Abeja_formatted.png"/>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a class="" href="#">Samsung</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a class="" href="#">iPhone</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a class="" href="#">Xiaomi</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a class="" href="#">One Plus</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a class="" href="#">LG</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a class="" href="#">Acer</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```